# Redirect of all page number to home page with .htaccess in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want that all the url of the type `http://www.example.com/page/x` are redirected to the home page `http://www.example.com`, where the `x` could be a number from 0 to 9 and all combination of them.

Actually my `.htaccess` has this instructions in the WordPress section.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: may try `add_action('init', 'redirect_home'); function() { if( is_page() { wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit; } }`

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it with the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your current code by this one in your htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^page/[0-9]+$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule after `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteRule ^()page/\d+ $1 [DPI,L]
```